# Meaning of retn4 in ida

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I am trying to understand a DLL. I am new to IDA disassembler. I came across this instruction. What does the following instruction mean ? I saw this in IDA 5.0 Freeware.

**retn 4**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`retn` in is an Assembly instruction "return near" as opposed to `retf` =  return far. According to https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ECE390/archive/fall2001/books/labmanual/inst-ref-ret.html `retn X` instruction is return + move the stack pointer X more bytes. This is typcially used by methods with calling conventions where callee is responsible for removing passed arguments from the stack such as [`__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx).